# GLSL Phong Light, Camera Problem

Tags: opengl, camera, glsl, light

I Just started write a phong shader

```
vert:
varying vec3 normal, eyeVec;
#define MAX_LIGHTS 8
#define NUM_LIGHTS 3
varying vec3 lightDir[MAX_LIGHTS];

void main() {
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;
    vec4 vVertex = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    eyeVec = -vVertex.xyz;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<NUM_LIGHTS; ++i){
        lightDir[i] = vec3(gl_LightSource[i].position.xyz - vVertex.xyz);
    }
}
```

I know that I need to get the camera position with `uniform`, but how, and where put this value?

ps. I'm using opengl 2.0

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to pass the camera position, because, well, there is no camera in OpenGL.

Lighting calculations are performed in eye/world space, i.e. after the multiplication with the modelview matrix, which also performs the "camera positioning". So actually you already got the right things in place. using `ftransform()` is a little inefficient, as you're doing half of what it does again (`gl_ModelviewMatrix * gl_Vertex`, you can make this into ftransform by adding `gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * eyeVec`)

So if your lights seem to move when your "camera" transforms, you're not transforming the light's positions properly. Either precompute the transformed light positions, or transform them in the shader as well. It's more a matter of choosen convention, less laid out constraint if using shaders.

Comment: "there is no camera in OpenGL" haha *mind blows*. But one could also say that the camera is always at the origin...

Comment: @Calvin1602: No there is no camera in OpenGL; or any other rasterizer to speak of. This is in difference to some physics based renderers that actually emulate the behaviour of real cameras. What you have in OpenGL are geometric transformations. This might sound like nitpicking but like they say, the devil is in the details.

Comment: I know that -_- I just wanted to say that it's weird the first time you hear that. Very counter-intuitive.